# Making a connection to my controller.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

I have a login page which is login.aspx.cs and i am trying to connect it to my Controller.cs page

This is the code i have put in the "protected void Page_Load"

```
Controller Controller = new Controller();
```

This is the code with this code i get an error message under the 2 of the "Controller" saying "controller" is a variable but used like a type

Can anyone help?

Comment: Pick a different name for the instance. `var someController = new Controller();`

Comment: This question was briefly closed as a duplicate, but the duplicate was for a different situation. If you can find a better duplicate then let's close it as that (and I'll remove my answer).

Comment: c# is case sensitive, naming a instance the same as the class name is a bad idea, could be confusing. This could work, `Controller controller = new Controller();` but I would choose a different name to the variable.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is Controller in your code? Is that a class you defined? Or is it an ASP.NET MVC controller?

Comment: Its a web api controller class that i have classed "Controller.cs". If thats what you mean. Will it be easier if i change the name?

Comment: @Joe You definitely shouldn't name your class the same as something in the framework. And your class name should be more specific, such as `ReportsApiController` or `PersonApiController`. But anyways, why in the world are you instantiating a Web API controller yourself on a Web Forms page?! There's not a good reason to do that.

Comment: Why is it not? I am new to this thats all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give your variable the same name as a class name. That causes a conflict. If you stuck to proper C# conventions, then local variables should always be camelCased. So in your case, it should be:

```
Controller controller = new Controller();
```

That will keep you from having a conflict.

Comment: It now says the namespace cannot be found, is there something i need to do in the controller.cs file

Comment: If the the class you're putting this code in isn't in the same namespace, you'll need to either fully qualify the class name (something like `MyNamespace.Controller`) or add a `using MyNamespace` at the top of the class you're putting the code in.